# Users with different permission levels are seeing different page layouts?

Tags: development, page-layout, publishing-site, administration

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection. And I have edited the EnterpriseWiki.aspx page layout , where I added some new columns and I have also remove the Page rating.

Now users with contributor permission will see the following page , including the modification :-

[image]

While users with Read Permission will see the default page layout as follow (including the Page rating which have been removed!!!):-

[image]

Also if they click on the left side term store (Standard or Document Type), they will get the following error:-

> Sorry, you don't have access to this page

and as i mentioned if i grant the Reader user a Contribute permission level, he is going to see the full modified page layout ..

Can anyone advice

Comment: Since it's not approved yet, the readers will not see the published version.. Approve the page layout and the updates should replicate!

Comment: The page is checked out. Please check in the page, approve and publish it , so that other users can see the change

Comment: in my setting users can see pending issues,, also if i approve it nothing will change. and if i add this user to the contributor group he will see the page layout...

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri ok i aproved the page but still Read user will see the defualt page layout !!!

Comment: @Unnie no the page status is pendding , but not checked-out, also inside my versioning settings i mentioned that any user with Read permission can view pending items,, so this is not a problem.. the issue is with the Fact that for some reasons Reader users will not be able to see the modified page layout, or to navigate through the term store...

Comment: @Unnie also users with Reader permission will not be able to see the Search box and the site navigation ,, please anyone adivce what is going on !!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri also i have added some javascripts inside the master page (seatle.master) which will display the current date & time, but users with read permission will not be able to see this also..

Comment: i check-out then check-in the page layout and the master pages , and i publish them as majot verisons and now the page layout is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check-Out then Check-In the page layout and the master pages, and I publish them as major versions and now the page layout is working well.